# How to model interrelated attributes in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I have a set of attributes, all calculable from each other:

```
 A = B * C
 B = A / C
 C = A / B
```

A, B, and C are all attributes of my model, so there is a function which takes a model that is missing one of them and returns a model which has all three specified.

Thus, there is a type-concept of a "solvable" model, which is one that is missing 0 or 1 attributes, and an "unsolvable" model, which is missing 2 or more. That is, a solvable model is one that can be converted, via one of the above functions (or without making any change), into a complete model.

**How can I model these concepts in my type system?** So far, I've tried using `Partial` or `Pick` to create individual types for each of these, but it was incredibly verbose and I couldn't get other parts of my app which consumed these functions to correctly compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if the following counts as "incredibly verbose" (it uses `Pick<>` internally, so maybe?) or if it runs into the same compilation problems you saw, but:

```
type MissingOneProperty<O extends object> = {
  [K in keyof O]: Pick<O, Exclude<keyof O, K>>
}[keyof O];
type MissingAtMostOneProperty<O extends object> =
  O | MissingOneProperty<O>;
```

The idea is that `MissingAtMostOneProperty<O>` is either `O` or it is missing exactly one property from `O`.  This probably only works for object types without index signatures (do you care?).

So if I define your model like this:

```
interface Model {
  a: number,
  b: number,
  c: number
}
```

I can declare a function that only accepts models missing at most one property:

```
declare function solveModel(
  solvableModel: MissingAtMostOneProperty<Model>
): Model;
solveModel({ a: 1, b: 2 }); // okay
solveModel({ b: 2, c: 0.5 }); // okay
solveModel({ a: 1, c: 0.5 }); // okay
solveModel({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 0.5 }); // okay
solveModel({ a: 1 }); // error, property "b" is missing
solveModel({ b: 2 }); // error, property "a" is missing
solveModel({ c: 0.5 }); // error, property "a" is missing
solveModel({}); // error, property "a" is missing
```

Looks reasonable to me.

---

To understand how that works, let's walk through what `MissingAtMostOneProperty<Model>` gets evaluated to:

```
MissingAtMostOneProperty<Model>
```

becomes, by the definition of `MissingAtMostOneProperty`:

```
Model | MissingOneProperty<Model>
```

which is, by the definition of `MissingOneProperty`:

```
Model | {[K in keyof Model]: Pick<Model, Exclude<keyof Model, K>>}[keyof Model]
```

which is, by [mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) over the `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'` properties of `Model`:

```
Model | {
  a: Pick<Model, Exclude<keyof Model, 'a'>,
  b: Pick<Model, Exclude<keyof Model, 'b'>,
  c: Pick<Model, Exclude<keyof Model, 'c'>
}[keyof Model]
```

which is, by noting that `keyof Model` is `'a'|'b'|'c'` and that [`Exclude<T, U>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.1.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1386-L1389) is a [conditional type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) that removes elements from unions:

```
Model | {
  a: Pick<Model, 'b'|'c'>,
  b: Pick<Model, 'a'|'c'>,
  c: Pick<Model, 'a'|'b'>
}['a'|'b'|'c']
```

which, by noting how `Pick<>` works, becomes:

```
Model | {
  a: { b: number, c: number },
  b: { a: number, c: number },
  c: { a: number, b: number }
}['a'|'b'|'c']
```

which, finally, by noting that [looking up](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types) a union of property keys in a type is the same as the union of the types of the properties, and by the definition of `Model`, turns into:

```
{a: number, b: number, c: number} 
  | { b: number, c: number }
  | { a: number, c: number }
  | { a: number, b: number }
```

Done!  You can see how you end up with a union of `Model` and all ways of removing one property from `Model`.

Hope that gives you some direction.  Good luck!

Comment: The verbosity was in creating `ModelWithoutA`, `ModelWithoutB`, etc. types. Not just in using `Pick`. This is neat, but I can't quite piece together what `MissingOneProperty<>` does.

Comment: Edited: tried explaining it a bit by walking through how it gets evaluated.